# Woocommerce: Display list of current category products in sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I would like to display a text list (on the sidebar) of all the products from the category that is currently being viewed. Here is an example: https://www.sunrisebotanics.com/collections/organic-essential-oils

So basically if someone goes to the "hats" category of my site it will show all the products of that category in the sidebar.

Is this even possible with a plugin of sorts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get current category and pass it in `WP_Query`

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query' => 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-slug2' // current category slug
        ),
    'post_type' => 'product'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Do I place this in my functions.php? Or how exactly do I use it. I'm not very experienced in code.

Comment: @user3612498 it should goes to widget, if you new in wordpress first search about  how to create a widget

Comment: I added the code to a widget but it doesn't seem to be working. I'll post the widget code below

Comment: Is there something missing in the code above? It doesn't output any text for me.

Comment: @user3612498 you should be able to work with `WP_Query` , this code just part of code that you need to load products

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about WP_Query or how to load the products. Are you willing to help some more?

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpb_load_widget() {
register_widget( 'wpb_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );

// Creating the widget 
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct(

// Base ID of your widget
'wpb_widget', 

// Widget name will appear in UI
__('WPBeginner Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), 

// Widget description
array( 'description' => __( 'Sample widget based on WPBeginner Tutorial', 
'wpb_widget_domain' ), ) 
);
}

// Creating widget front-end

public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

// This is where you run the code and display the output
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'tax_query' => 
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'category-slug2' // current category slug
    ),
'post_type' => 'product'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
}

// Widget Backend 
public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];
}
else {
$title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
}
// Widget admin form
?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 
'Title:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" 
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?
php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
}

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( 
$new_instance['title'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
} // Class wpb_widget ends here
```